# How to count all RecyclerView items in UiAutomator for not different items

Tags: android-uiautomator

I have to swipe to the end of the list and to count the elements, but these elements are not all different. How can I count them?

Answer (score 0):

You can add those elements in a list and scroll down after adding them.
You can add all those list elements in HashSet which will ensure that no elements are counted twice.
You can swipe down the recycler view using UiDevice object.
I can give more detail and code about this once I get to know about your scenario in more detail.

Comment: The problem is that some elements are duplicate, so at the bottom of the list, I will definitely not have all the objects using HashSet. If I try to put them into an Array, after I scroll down, the last item from the list before scrolling will appear again in the new list after scrolling so it will be count again.  One option which I have think about, is to get name & location for the last item in the list and after I swipe down, to check what's the index of that element, take the list size and subtract this index ... it's indeed a complex action